# Android don't call onPause and onStop when looping process is running

Tags: java, android, lifecycle

I create a very simple android application with a single button name is 'Generate'. The activity handle onclick event.

```
public void autoGenerate(View view) throws InterruptedException {
    Log.v("Hello", "I'm Duy");
    final int count = 10000;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        Log.v("Count", String.valueOf(i));
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

I've added log to onPause and onStop.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Log.v("Life Cycle", "onPause ...");
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    Log.v("Life Cycle", "onStop ...");
    super.onStop();
}
```

I click Generate button, this application print the counter value in LogCat. Then I click home button on my phone, there's no callback happened util the looping is completed. I totally don't understand this case because I think when the app disappear, system should call the callback onPause and onStop.

Can anyone help me? I'm just a beginner who start reading android e-book.

Comment: You should pretty much never call `Thread.sleep();` on the main thread. Ever. As you've now noticed it interrupts the life-cycle methods of your Activity.

Comment: theres no callback as im suspecting (Thread.sleep(1000);) sleeping the thread 1sec  X 10000 =  2.778 hours

Answer (score 1):

Once you entered in a loop, application will not exit until your loop finishes. Instead of using loop directly, start a new thread to execute the loop. The even if you close the application, loop will be running in background.

Comment: I'm understood. So, the onclick event handle my click for a longtime, callback functions should be in the same thread with the loop, It is a UI thread. System need to wait util the main thread complete the loop. That's why there's no callback happened here. I should never use UI thread for task that take long time any more.

Comment: @DuyNguyenThanh yes, you have to use runOnUiThread() and create a new thread to perform loop or any other operation

Comment: @DuyNguyenThanh Accept my answer if it helps

Answer (score 1):

UI click events are processed from main thread of your application.
Your for loop is blocking the main thread and hence onPause lifecycle call is delayed.